# How to obtain difference between groups at specific timepoints (mixed effects models)

Tags: r, mixed-model

Given two groups of subjects (A & B) tested at multiple timepoints (A-T1, A-T2, A-T3 / B-T1, B-T2), with each subject tested multiple times at each timepoint - how can one build a single model to 1. Test if at specific timepoint (i.e. A-T2) group A is different from overall group B and 2. Test if there is a difference across time within groups?

Ideally, it would be great to test both hypotheses with a single model.

For now I am considering timepoint and group as fixed effects and subject as random effects:

```
lmer(measure ~ TP*group + (1|subject), df)
```